# Issue with iterator value in parallel task

Tags: java, arrays, iterator, future, threadpoolexecutor

I have a for loop as part of a callable class that gets executed several times in parallel by a threadpoolexecutor. The rest of the callable class seems to be functioning appropriately. That's important I think. Only the iterator is causing an issue. So here's the 411: The loop runs, it searches for an alarm in a list of discretes. When it finds one (which it does whenever I trip any of them) it's supposed to create an alarm object and give it the ID of its position in the list. This is what the iterator is for.

***Until I made this task execute in parallel, the iterator (int i) returned its position in the array every time. Now it only returns a value of 0 despite properly iterating over the array.***

Here's the relevant code of the callable. Are iterators not thread safe or something? I'm baffled.

```
        //Create a list to store discretes
        boolean[] boolist = new boolean[1024];
        //Read values from the site and assign them to the boolean array
        mbc.readInputDiscretes(1, 0, boolist);
        for (int i = 0; i < boolist.length; i++) {
        //Checks to see if the alarm is alarmed. Do not be alarmed if the alarm is alarmed.
            if(boolist[i]){
                //For each value of true we create a new alarm tag, set the alarm to active within the system, record its site ID and its Tag ID.
                TagInfo alarmtag = new TagInfo(true, InfoBox.getSiteID(), i);
                //THE ITERATOR ABOVE ONLY RETURNS 0, HOWEVER IT ITERATES THROUGH THE LIST PROPERLY. SO ALL TAGS ARE NOTICED BUT RETURN WITH AN ID OF 0. AHHHHHH.
                //Add the tag to the list to return.
                alarmtags.add(alarmtag);
            }
        }
```

Edit:

By request, here's the relevant pieces of the TagInfo class:

```
public class TagInfo {
private int siteID;                 //ID # of the site this tag belongs to
private int tagID;                  //ID # of the tag itself
private int tagOffset;              //Integer 1-1024 related to the tags read position at its given site
private int tagType;                //The type of tag (not yet implemented, just thought it would be useful eventually)
private int tagEscDly;              //The amount of time to wait before we raise the priority level of an alarm referencing this specific tag
private Timestamp lastPolled;       //The last time this site was checked
private boolean alarmstatus;        //The alarm status of this specific tag, e.g. in alarm or not in alarm

//Default empty constructor for TagInfo object
public TagInfo(){}

//Overloaded constructor for faster initialization of objects and fewer method calls
public TagInfo(boolean alarmstatus, int siteID, int tagID){
    this.alarmstatus = alarmstatus;
    this.siteID = siteID;
    this.tagID = tagID;
}
```

Here's the code calling the callable:

```
        //Invoke run method on each site simultaneously, store results in a list
        List<Future<List<TagInfo>>> futures=threadmaker.invokeAll(active_sites.stream().map(site -> new TAG_SCANNER(site, loggr)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Post the declaration of `alarmtag`. Also a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be nice.

Comment: I thought this line was the declaration?
     TagInfo alarmtag = new TagInfo(true, InfoBox.getSiteID(), i);

Comment: Can you provide the code of `TagInfo` (constructor and members delaration at least)

Comment: @LaurentSimon post updated, sorry about that

Comment: If I understand properly, you said that despite the loop with proper values for `i`, the `tagID` value in `alarmtag` (`TagInfo` class) is always set to 0.

Comment: @LaurentSimon This is correct. Before I paralleled this task, the value of tagID was always correctly set to the value of the iterator i as it relates to the boolean list boolist. This allowed me to uniquely identify alarms per site.

Now that the task runs in parallel, the tagID value winds up being set to 0 every time an alarm is active.

Comment: Before entering the loop, can you add an explicit test that `boolist.length > 1` to confirm that ?

Comment: If the previous test is okay, in the `TagInfo`  class, can you declare tagID as final to ensure that it is never changed elsewhere after ?

Comment: @LaurentSimon You're going to think I'm stupid. I had been using setters instead of that overloaded constructor before I'd read something about anti-patterns and blah blah blah functional code junk. Point is, the methods I'd been using before were setAlarmStatus(), setSiteID() and NOT setTagID() but setTagOffset(). If you look at the comments in my TagInfo class everything starts to make sense.

D'oh!

Comment: Sorry, I meant `alarmtags`

Comment: Don't put an answer in the question. Put it in the answer section then accept it.

Comment: @takendarkk Done. Says I have to wait two days to accept it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The issue lay in the use of an improper variable.